# Web3 sending custom tokens by using the transfer function. Need to set the from account

Tags: web3js, erc-20

Looking to code WEB3 to be able to send custom tokens out programmatically.

However, I am not sure where to specify the user account that actually sends the token.

This is the code I have thus far. I

```
var custom_token_address = req.params.customtoken;
  var abi = loadABI();
  var MyContract = web3.eth.contract(abi);
  var myContractInstance = MyContract.at('0x416DFae2FED9B7a282E8beaC750210A7d952204A');

web3.eth.contract(abi).at(custom_token_address).transfer('0x61E28c6d1e5159E2415644FBBE5E0D40542e4C8c', 10000);
```

Where is is that I set the from account in all of this?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Note: the below is with web3.js 0.20 (the syntax changes for 1.0.0)]

You can either set the [default from account](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethdefaultaccount) for all transactions:

```
web3.eth.defaultAccount = '0x........';
```

Or you can specify a [transaction object](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethsendtransaction) on a case-by-case basis as the last parameter in [your method](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#contract-methods):

```
web3.eth.contract(abi).at(custom_token_address).transfer('0x61E28c6d1e5159E2415644FBBE5E0D40542e4C8c', 10000, {from: '0x........'});
```