# web3.js why is there dots when calling addresses

Tags: web3js, erc-20

I'm trying to use web3.js to use the "transfer" function of an ERC20 token.

I've found this example here : [How to send ERC20 token using Web3 API?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/24828/how-to-send-erc20-token-using-web3-api) which seems good (but kind of old)

But I notice they almost always put "..." after an address like so :

`var contractAddress = "0x8...";`

or

`"data": contract.transfer.getData("0xCb...", 10, {from: "0x26..."}),`

Why is that ?

Comment: The dost are there to just show more characters are there, a placeholder. They just don't want to reveal the full address. Ignore the dots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They just don't want to reveal the addresses and keys to everyone on stackexchange.

To get it to work, you must use a full address, without the dots.