# How can i create a token ERC20 with a customized function

Tags: solidity, remix, tokens, erc-20, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I want to create a and ERC20 token with a specially function.

The question is the following:

PERSON A: Create 1000 example Tokens.

PERSON B: Execute a function that mint 10 of that example Tokens.

Im starting to code in solidity and im fighting with that. Thanks! :)

Comment: Did you try using OpenZeppelin contracts as a base?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new ERC20 token using openZeppelin contracts.

[Basic ERC20 token](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/erc20)

And if you need to send the token to another account by either using some wallet or send it using some lib like web3js, etherjs etc

[Web3](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/24828/how-to-send-erc20-token-using-web3-api)

[EtherJS](https://ethereum.org/fr/developers/tutorials/send-token-etherjs/)

You can also create a function to mint token in your contract itself

```
function mint(address to, uint256 amount) public {
    _mint(to, amount);
}
```

Use some access control to restrict it from all wallet

[Access Control](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/access-control)