# How to send USDT transaction in BSC (using web3)

Tags: web3js, bsc, usdt

I just learned how to send BNB from one wallet to another in Binance Smart Chain.

It looks like

```
const account = web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount('xxxxxxx')
web3.eth.accounts.wallet.add(account);
web3.eth.sendTransaction({
    from: address1,
    to: address2,
    value: '100000000000',
    gas: 5000000,
    gasPrice: 18e9,
}, callback)
```

And this code sends BNB from one account to another one

But how to do the same with USDT?
Maybe, do I have to include USDT's contractAbi?

Answer (score 1):

Need to work with ERC20 standard through contract ABI.

See some examples:

This one: https://piyopiyo.medium.com/how-to-send-erc20-token-with-web3-js-99ed040693ce

This one: [How to send ERC20 token using Web3 API?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/24828/how-to-send-erc20-token-using-web3-api)

Keep asking for questions, and if this answer was enough, please choose it as correct.

Comment: Thank you so much, but I met some problems. Maybe my version of web3 is newer then in your articles, but I  haven't got ".at(...)" method (using in web3.eth.contract(minABI).at(tokenAddress))
Also I have no .transfer(...) method. I can only call it by contract.methods.transfer(...)

Comment: Yes, Web3 versions of articles are older. However, you can refer to the updated functions:
https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.7.3/
But basically you need to call the ABI of the token contract you have.. Please choose it answer as correct.