# Ethereum : testrpc using different account for transaction

Tags: solidity

I am new to ethereum.
I have a simple contract (using solidity) where i am transferring limited number of amount.
I am able to send amount from default account to other account [Which is web3.eth.accounts[0] to other account]
how can i do the transaction from different account [from account 2 to account 3 and etc]. ?

is there any way to setting i can do to change the default account ?

Comment: See [this question and answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/24309/web3-sending-custom-tokens-by-using-the-transfer-function-need-to-set-the-from/24316#24316)

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at this Web3 [API](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethsendtransaction) to transfer amount from one account to another. You need to have the address of both accounts.

the code will be like this -

```
web3.eth.sendTransaction({from: <account2 adr>, to: <account3 adr>, value: <amount>})
```

There is no need to change the setting, you can just mention from which account you want to transfer amount.

Hope this helps.